# Why is there a tag for "zones-of-though"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The tag "zones-of-though" is clearly a typo but I am unable to correct it.  It should be "Zones-Of-Thought"

Answer (score 4):

Done, I've renamed the tag (using the moderator tools to do it behind the scenes, though for two questions it would have been ok to just retag those two questions).